# Nextjs 13 - Webpack just show one css file in dev, needed in dev see the source map (css files) in detail

Tags: sass, source-maps, next.js13, webpack-5

first sorry if I write some bad english (not my native language). Im new in Nextjs and im using version 13.4 and for css i use SASS I have a problem with webpack. When I was using just react in dev on browser i can do something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUm9j.png)
With inspect i can know where is the file who do the style (in tooltip give me the right path too) but in nextjs 13.4 in browser when im dev I have something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVVZJ.png)
Everything is in one file and it make a little more hard when debugging. I tried to search for some solutions on web but i can't find nothing who helped me.

When I stopped trying my next.config.js was like this.

**My next.config.js:**

```
/** u/type {import('next').NextConfig} */

require("dotenv").config();

const path = require("path");

const nextConfig = {

env: {

REACT_APP_API_URL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,

REACT_APP_API_URL1: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL1,

REACT_APP_LANGUAGES: process.env.REACT_APP_LANGUAGES,

REACT_APP_LANGUAGES_GT: process.env.REACT_APP_LANGUAGES_GT,

REACT_APP_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE: process.env.REACT_APP_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,

REACT_APP_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_FORCED_REDIRECT: process.env.REACT_APP_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_FORCED_REDIRECT,

REACT_APP_WEBSITE_NAME: process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSITE_NAME,

},

sassOptions: {

includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],

},

webpack: (config, { dev }) => {

if (dev) {

config.devtool = "source-map";

}

config.module.rules.push({

test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,

use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],

});

config.module.rules.push({

test: /\.css$/i,

include: /u/fortawesome[\\/]|glightbox[\\/]|leaflet[\\/]/,

use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],

});

return config;

},

};
```

module.exports = nextConfig;

Is my first time posting I dont know if I forgot to give some info.
I dont know if at this moment there isn't a solution, but if exist can you help me please?